# Ajax запрос - загрузка данных

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Добрый вечер! Столкнулась с проблемой: на странице необходимо загрузить картинки с помощью Ajax запроса, при первой загрузке страницы необходимо, что бы выводились случайные картинки, но если в поле поиска ничего не вводить картинки не должны загружаться. Как правильно это реализовать?

```
$(function () {
      function renderList() {
        var pic = $('.search__box__input').val();
        var API_KEY = '2671443-f70b44031fad9176b9185b139';
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://pixabay.com/api/?key=" + API_KEY + "&q=" + pic + "&per_page=7&lang=ru",
            success: function(data) {
              if ( parseInt(data.totalHits) === 0  || pic === '')  {
                return false;
              } else 
                // console.log(data);
                var piclist = tmpl($('#grid-template').html(), data);
                $('.grid').remove();
                $('.activity-grid').append(piclist);
                 $('.grid').masonry({
                    // options
                    itemSelector: '.grid__item',
                    columnWidth: 300
                });
            }
        });
    }
    $('#search__form').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        renderList();
    });
    renderList();
 });
```

Также HTML :

```
div class="activity-grid">
       <h2 class="activity-grid__title">Discover holiday activity ideas</h2>
            <script type="text/html" id="grid-template">
                <div class="grid">
                     <% for (var i =0; i < hits.length; i++) { %>
                         <div class="grid__item
                             <% if ((i==5)||(i==4)){%>
                                  grid__item--width2
                                    <%}%>" 
        style="background: url(<%=hits[i].webformatURL%>) center no-repeat; 
                                        background-size: 100% 100%">
                    <p class="grid__item--text">
                      <%=hits[i].tags%>
                       </p>
                   </div>
              <%}; %>
                    </div>
                </script>
            </div>
        <section class="search">
        <div class="search__box">

            <p class="search__box__title" >
                Discover holiday activity ideas
            </p>
            <form action="#" method="GET" id="search__form">
                <p class="search__box__subtitle">Hi! What are your holiday interests?</p>
                <input class="search__box__input" type="text" name="" placeholder="Enter your interests">
                <input class="search__box__submit" type="submit" name="" value="Search partners">
            </form>
        </div>
```

Comment: _при первой загрузке страницы необходимо, что бы выводились случайные картинки, но если в поле поиска ничего не вводить картинки не должны загружаться._ - не совсем понятно. Получается что если в поле поиска при загрузке ничего нет то и случайные картинки грузить не нужно.

Answer (score 2):

возможно необходимо проверить есть ли что то в поле ввода поиска и затем реализовать логику в зависимости от результата.

```
if (!document.getElementsByClassName("search__box__input")[0].value) { 
    /* если поле ввода поиска пустое */ 
};
```

Comment: так при загрузке страницы оно же автоматически пустое, но всё равно нужны картинки случайные разместить, если прописать условие для пустого поля поиска, то при загрузке страницы не будут выводится картинки совсем

Comment: при пустом поле запрос который вернет рандомные картинки, иначе в зависимости от того что в него введено - не подходит?

Comment: К  сожалению нет.

Comment: Короче, как логику прописать не знаю, просто добавила атрибут к input  required  - поле в любом случае должно быть заполнено. Такой вариант может иметь право на существование?

Comment: если результат работает как вы ожидаете то конечно.

Comment: работает ) спасибо за помощь)